# How do I stop building synthetic species in a full world?

Tags: stellaris

I'm starting to reach end game and my capital is filled to the brim. I put up the growth discouragament decision to curb the pop growth so people won't go.

Problem is, I decided to take the Synthetic Evolution path with my Ascension Perks, so now my system capital has 3 robotocis jobs that constantly pump my planet full of robots.

How do I stop this, or deal with it?

(The game is on patch 2.2.2)

Comment: Apparently, there's a mod just for this https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1595251631

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable individual jobs - just move all workers to different work slots. Press the +/- buttons in the population tab on the line with that building.

Comment: Ah. Should have tought of that. It seems to have worked, altough the freshly laid off specialists aren't exactly happy... Ah well, that's a problem for me to solve on my own.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with patch 2.2.3 there is a new decision to stop robot production:

> Added a new decision to stop or continue Robot, Droid, and Synthetic Pop assembly, and made this work independently of organic population controls

Here is the link to the full [patch notes](https://steamcommunity.com/games/281990/announcements/detail/1718587807622223328).